# VSO builds not running

Tags: azure-devops

Our VSO builds have stopped running.

When queueing up a new build, the console output remains as "The build has been queued and is waiting to start." and doesn't budge:

[image: The build has been queued and is waiting to start]

We are using the host agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is on Microsoft's side.  See [service blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsoservice/archive/2015/08/04/issues-with-visual-studio-online-hosted-build-service-8-4-investigating.aspx):

Comment: I completely disagree. Firstly, these are not one-time things.  Just looking at the past week, there were performance issues with the hosted builds on the 24th, 25th, 26th and 27th.  Every other day there is an issue. Secondly, if others are troubleshooting the same problem (builds not starting), they may not be aware of the VSTS Service Blog and so this answer may save them from tearing their hair out.

Comment: So a comment pointing them to check the status of the VSO blog may be helpful.  It is certainly not the solution to a build that continuously hangs, nor, as you point out, the numerous threads where builds hang but there is no reported outage.

Comment: Yea this always happens :(

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the relevant agent is enabled in VSTS.

Go to `Builds` -> `Definitions` then click on `Manage` in the details section. The agents are listed under `Agent Queues`.

If the agent is not enabled, the build will not start.